# How to run a command for each number in a range

Tags: shell

I want to do something like

```
specmd file5.awe
specmd file6.awe
specmd file7.awe
specmd file8.awe
specmd file9.awe
specmd file10.awe
specmd file11.awe
specmd file12.awe
```

Is there a good way to do this? The best way I can think of is something like

```
ruby -e "10.upto(15){|i| puts i}" | xargs -I {} specmd file{}.awe
```

Which obviously isn't a very good way to do it since it depends on ruby and feels like ruby should be unneccesary in this case.

Note: there are more files (eg: `file4.awe`,`file13.awe`) which I *don't* want, so any globbing (probably?) won't do what I want.

Comment: A `for` loop and brace expansion is what you want, `for i in {5..12}`

Comment: yep, was finishing writing a more complete answer, same suggestion. "Modern" bash has some niceties.

Comment: you can also replace that ruby with "echo {10..15}"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In bash, you can create loops using the builtin command for iterating through a range:

```
for i in {5..12}
do 
    specmd file${i}.awe
done
```

There are more options in for for other similar situations, I will leave here a link for that.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/

Comment: Note that that `{5..12}` syntax does come from `zsh` (it's now also supported by `ksh` and `yash -o brace-expand`). Actually, with the missing quotes around `${i}`, that code looks more like `zsh` syntax than `bash` syntax.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old question, but I could not resist.

No for loop required, no while loop required, just pure command-line bash:

```
echo file{5..12}.awe | xargs -n1 specmd
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for f in file[5-9].awe file1[012].awe
do  : stuff with "$f" files
done
```

...not *all* globs are equal.

else you can do:

```
x=4
while  [ 13 -gt "$((x+=1))" ]
do     : stuff with "file$x.awe"
done
```

...which has the advantage of generating its iterator while iterating, and works by default in practically any scripted shell *(as is also true of the globs)*.

Comment: cool stuff. Are you sure $((x+=1)) works everywhere? I thought it was bash specific.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro - im not sure it works *everywhere*, but am fairly certain it does [*practically everywhere*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04).

Comment: POSIX compliance hmmm...thanks for the link

Comment: You can also write `for ((x=5 ; x <= 12 ; x++)); do` ... loop body ... `done`.  Although `local x` inside the arithmetic expression doesn't work, so inside a function you should still declare your loop variables before the loop.  And if you're going to use arithmetic expansion, your shell will also support arithmetic expressions, right?  So your loop could be `local x=4; while ((12 >= x+=1)); do` ...  That looks a lot cleaner than using `[ 13 -gt ..]` for the compare, IMHO.  (bleh, POSIX says `++` isn't guaranteed to be supported)

Comment: Ok, nvm, I checked and `while ((expression))` doesn't work in `dash`.  POSIX sh only specifies `$((expression))` arithmetic expansion, not `((expression))` arithmetic *expressions*.

Comment: @PeterCordes - yes - those are the expansions. you can do as many as you like within the substitution, but the result is a single value substituted to the command-line. whats wrong with `[ 13 -gt ...`?

Comment: @mikeserv: Nothing's *wrong* with it, just that if POSIX sh supported arithmetic expressions, it'd be more concise to do the compare inside the arithmetic context.  `while ((12 >= x+=1));do` is easier to read than nesting two different things (an arithmetic expansion on the command line of `[`).

Comment: @PeterCordes - i dunno that it would make more sense - those are shell metacharacters in that form - and they introduce a new a process. and besides: `math(){ return "$((!($1)))"; }; math x+=1 && ...`. its an expansion - its not an evaluation. the shell is a macro language - it expands stuff. it works with strings.

Comment: Bash doesn't use a new process for arithmetic expressions.  `strace -eclone bash -c 'x=4; while ((13 > x++));do /bin/true "$x";done'` proves this.  (Works on Linux, where `fork()` is implemented on top of the `clone(2)` system call).

Comment: @PeterCordes - no shells due, but it was difficult enough getting the shell devs to agree on an expansion. the `bash` dev wanted `$[math]`. they just dont agree. and `(( ... ))` with its own return and whatever is hard to standardize because they already have their own way of doing things. by the way - `bash` may not get a subshell for math, but considering its math eval performance, it might as well. `bash` is *the slowest* shell of all - especially at math. all of those weird syntax forms take their toll - there are simple shells, and there is `bash`. thats how it is.

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh` you can simplify command with a special "loop" `repeat`:

```
n=5; m=12; repeat $((m-n+1)) specmd file$((n++)).awe
```

Comment: also in *the `csh`*

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
parallel specmd file{}.awe ::: {5..12}
seq 5 12 | parallel specmd file{}.awe
parallel specmd ::: file{5..12}.awe
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a C-style for-loop in `bash` or `ksh93`:

```
for ((i=5;i<=12;++i)); do specmd "file$i.awe"; done
```

Using brace expansion:

```
for f in file{5..13}.awe; do specmd "$f"; done
```

Or, with `xargs`, in a similar was as you had:

```
printf '%s\n' {5..13} | xargs -I {} specmd file{}.awe
```

Answer (score 0):

More alternatives for `zsh`

```
autoload zargs # best in ~/.zshrc
zargs -n1 file{5..12}.awe -- specmd
```

or:

```
for f (file{5..12}.awe) specmd $f
```

Answer (score 0):

### Define a reusable method

```
lineRange() { 
  sed -n $1,$2p
}
```

#### Call it

By piping the output of something to your method

```
cat someFileName | lineRange 10 20
```

This example shows a file, but only lines 10 to 20

Now you can pipe that output to some other program with xargs

```
cat someFileName | lineRange 10 20 | xargs -n1 whateverCommandYouWish
```